# How create and assign tkinter variable for every items in a list

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I am trying to create a program that allows user to select from a list of symptoms they have and find the disease.i added a drop-down menu that contains the symptoms in checkboxes

```
clicked2=StringVar(root) 
clicked2.set(symptoms[0]) 
  
drop2=OptionsMenu(root,variable=clicked2,value="options :")
drop2.pack()
checked=[] #contain the checked symptoms

def checkedSymptom:
    if (var2.get()=1):
        checked.append(symptom)
        print(symptom)
    elif (var2.get()=0):
        pass
```

this is the part I'm having an issue with

```
for symptom in symptoms:
    var2=IntVar()
    drop2['menu'].add_checkbutton(label=symptom,onvalue=1,offvalue=0, variable=var2, command=checkedSymptom)
```

> symptoms here is the list of symptoms

but since it loops through the list of symptoms each time it loops the variable that holds the checkbox is overwritten. so at the end only the last item on the list does anything when checked.

-

Comment: Use a dictionary to store those `IntVar`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a dictionary to store the variables:

```
vars = {}
for symptom in symptoms:
    var2 = IntVar(root)
    drop2['menu'].add_checkbutton(label=symptom, onvalue=1, offvalue=0, variable=var2, command=checkedSymptom)
    vars[symptom] = var2
```

Then use the dictionary inside `checkedSymptom()` to check which symptom is checked:

```
def checkedSymptom():
    checked.clear()
    checked.extend([key for key in vars if vars[key].get() == 1])
    print(checked)
```

Comment: It took me a while to understand it but thanks it solved my problem